# Generate Series number depend on Input

Tags: sql-server, generate-series

Please let me know how to generate following series in SQL ,I have input and need output such as :
[This is my Input and needed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoxXT.jpg)

Comment: The formula looks simple, assuming input is X, output = 15 * Math.Ceil(X/15). Do you need to insert these values?

Comment: No just select X,Output , but your formula not working please test it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `FLOOR` like this

```
;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY n.t) AS Input
   FROM (VALUES (1),(2), (3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS n(t)
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2), (3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS n1(t)
) -- return input table  from 0 --> 100
SELECT t.Input, (FLOOR((t.Input - 1)/15) + 1) *15 AS Output
FROM temp t
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/NYZ63298

Comment: Thanks ,but for Input 15 the output should be 15 not 30 , I can't make that , please help?

Comment: You could change to (t.Input - 1)/15